# Integrate does not work on my expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I am trying to integrate a simple equation. The code is as follows

```
V = -V0/(1 + Exp[(r - R)/a]);
s0 = 2 Sqrt[1/b^3] Exp[-r^2/(2*b^2)]/(Pi)^(1/4);
s1 = Sqrt[2/3]*Sqrt[1/b^3]*(3 - 2*r^2/b^2)*Exp[-r^2/(2*b^2)];
s2 = Sqrt[1/b^3]*Exp[-r^2/(2*b^2)]*(4*r^4/b^4 - 20*r^2/b^2 + 15)/(2*Sqrt[15]*Pi^(1/4));
s3 = Sqrt[1/b^3]*Exp[-r^2/(2*b^2)]*(-8*r^6/b^6 + 84*r^4/b^4 - 210*r^2/b^2 + 105)/(6*Sqrt[210]*Pi^(1/4));
s4 = Sqrt[1/b^3]*Exp[-r^2/(2*b^2)]*(16*r^8/b^8 - 288*r^6/b^6 + 1512*r^4/b^4 - 2520*r^2/b^2 + 945)/(144*Sqrt[105]*Pi^(1/4));
s00 = s0*s0*V*r^2;
s01 = s0*s1*V*r^2;
s00ws = Integrate[s00, {r, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> b > 0]
s01ws = Integrate[s01, {r, 0, Infinity}, Assumptions -> b > 0]
```

When I evaluate the above integral I get the following output

```
Integrate[-((4 E^(-(r^2/b^2)) r^2 V0)/(
  b^3 (1 + E^((r - R)/a)) Sqrt[\[Pi]])), {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> b > 0]

Integrate[-((2 Sqrt[2/3] E^(-(r^2/b^2)) r^2 (3 - (2 r^2)/b^2) V0)/(
  b^3 (1 + E^((r - R)/a)) \[Pi]^(1/4))), {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, 
 Assumptions -> b > 0]
```

*Mathematica* did not integrate the equation at all. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE!   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You use `Sqrt[[Pi]]` instead of `Sqrt[Pi]`, and `[Infinity]` instead of `\[Infinity]`. (That last one might be a copy-paste error.)

Comment: Please format your code properly to make it readable. Indent by four blanks so that it is in a codeblock.

Comment: `s00ws` reduces, up to a constant, to `Integrate[( (E^-(u + d/2)^2) (u^2) )/Cosh[d u - e], {u, 0, Infinity}]` for constant `d, e`. I see no particular reason for that to have a closed form…

Comment: @PatrickStevens Displaying `Sqrt[[Pi]]` is caused by the parser on the SE side. If you try to edit the question you will see that the `\\` are actually present, i.e. you have to escape those backslashes

Comment: First point is that you should not introduce s2, s3 and s4. They were not used in the integration and needlessly increases the complexity of your question. I plotted s00 as a function of r using a Manipulate to control the other variables. `Manipulate[
 Plot[-((4 E^(-(r^2/b^2)) r^2 V0)/(
   b^3 (1 + E^((r - R)/a)) Sqrt[\[Pi]])), {r, 0, 4}],
 {{R, 1}, 0.1, 10},
 {{a, 1}, 0.1, 10},
 {{b, 1}, 0.1, 2},
 {{V0, 1}, 0.1, 100}
 ]` It appears to go to zero at high r values. When I attempt to integrate s00 by substituting 1 for the parameters a, b, R and V0 it also will not integrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using π rather than Pi in the equations you gave. I think this is what you wanted.

When I substitute in 1 for the variables a, b, R and V0 it will not integrate in a closed form.

```
Integrate[-((4 E^-r^2 r^2)/((1 + E^(-1 + r)) Sqrt[π])),
 {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, NIntegrate works.

```
NIntegrate[-((4 E^-r^2 r^2)/((1 + E^(-1 + r)) Sqrt[π])),
 {r, 0, Infinity}]
```

-0.470468

To see how the variables affect the results you can plot the curve as a function of r and wrap the plot and numerical integration in a Manipulate.

```
Manipulate[
 Column[{
   Plot[-((4 E^(-(r^2/b^2)) r^2 V0)/(
     b^3 (1 + E^((r - R)/a)) Sqrt[π])), {r, 0, 4}, 
    ImageSize -> 400],
   Framed[
    NIntegrate[-((4 E^(-(r^2/b^2)) r^2 V0)/(
      b^3 (1 + E^((r - R)/a)) Sqrt[π])),
     {r, 0, Infinity}],
    Background -> LightCyan
    ]
   }],

 {{R, 1}, 0.1, 10, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{a, 1}, 0.1, 10, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{b, 1}, 0.1, 2, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{V0, 1}, 0.1, 100, Appearance -> "Open"}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can change the values for R, a, b or V0 and see the result in the plot and the result of the numerical integration.